# Pandas string filtering by position with variable lengths

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a string column. The strings are either 2 or 3 characters long, and I have to filter out string whose third character is 'W'. So far I have

```
df[df.col_name.str[2] == 'W']
```

This works as long as df.col_name has strings with both 2 and 3 characters in them. However, when df.col_name only contains strings with 2 characters, the code crashes with the error:

```
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Is there any way to make this work for both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `apply` function which takes a custom function as a parameter. The custom function can include any arbitrary logic, in your case it checks whether the third character is a 'W'.

This should do the work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','ab','abW']})

def custom_filter(str):
    if len(str) >= 3 and str[2] == 'W':
        return str[2]
    else:
        return ""


df['new'] = df['A'].apply(custom_filter)

print(df['new'])
```

A shorter approach which does not make use of the `custom_filter` function is:

```
df[df['A'].apply(lambda x: len(x)>=3 and x[2]=='W')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.Series.str.pad`.

The idea is to pad with whitespace before extracting the 3rd element, assuming you are not searching *for* whitespace.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['abcd', 'ab', 'abWdfa', 'abW', 'abWabc']})

res = df.loc[df['A'].str.pad(3, 'right').str[2] == 'W']

print(res)

#         A
# 2  abWdfa
# 3     abW
# 4  abWabc
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this:

```
len(col_name.str) == 3 and col_name.str[2] == 'W'
```

If length < 3, the latter one will not be executed.

Comment: @Aran-Fey why? 0x51ba did this in his answer. And I tested OK.Oh, and mine is Python 2.7.

Comment: Nowhere in his answer does 0x51ba call `len` on `col_name.str`. I don't have python 2, but in python 3 this throws a `TypeError: object of type 'StringMethods' has no len()`.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Isn't `df.col_name.str` a `string`? I notice that OP done the comparison by `df.col_name.str[2] == 'W'`, that's why I think `df.col_name.str` is a `string`.

Comment: No. That's a dataframe column full of strings.